# Unable to make multiple calls to single Jquery function

Tags: jquery

Apologies again - this is probably down to my lack of knowledge with JQuery - but I have set up the following function whihc when passed a parameter which attempt to check for and then remove some dynamically added fields  (the check should stop the removal attempt being carried out - if not needed)

```
jQuery.fn.clearFields = function ( clearField ) { 

     var clearfield_search = "#"+clearField+"_search";
     var clearfield_link   = "#"+clearField+"_link";
     var clearfield_search_label = "label[for='"+clearField+"_search']";
     var clearfield_link_label = "label[for='"+clearField+"_link']";
     alert("About to Remove");

     if ($(clearfield_search).length > 0 ) { 
                                //Removal of Label and Field (Attempted) 
                                //removal of inital break & labels
                                $(clearfield_search_label).prev('br').remove();
                                $(clearfield_search_label).remove();
                                $(clearfield_link_label).prev('br').remove();
                                $(clearfield_link_label).remove();
                                //Removal of fields
                                $(clearfield_link).remove();
                                $(clearfield_search).remove();
     }
     alert("Removed");
}
```

But my dilemma is I can't see to make explicit (multiple calls)  to this function -    - such as

```
jQuery.fn.clearFields("ebsco");

jQuery.fn.clearfields("summon");
```

it seems only the first function call is executed - then nothing else happens - very frustrating.

Do I have to implement the calls using a for loop or the .each method - or I'm guessing there's something more fundamental I'm missing - or there is perhaps an even better cleaner way of doing this ?

Again any feedback much appreciated

Comment: NB: You should extend `jQuery`, not `jQuery.fn` if you don't intend to use it on selectors, i.e., like `$(selector').clearFields()`.

Comment: Why extend JQuery at all? Why not just declare this as a normal function?

Answer (score 0):

As per Nate's comment, something like this:

```
var clearField = function ( clearField ) { 

     var $clearfield_search = $("#"+clearField+"_search");
     var $clearfield_link   = $("#"+clearField+"_link");
     var $clearfield_search_label = $("label[for='"+clearField+"_search']");
     var $clearfield_link_label = $("label[for='"+clearField+"_link']");
     alert("About to attempt remove");

     if ($clearfield_search.length > 0 ) { 
                                //Removal of Label and Field (Attempted)
                                //removal of inital break & labels
                                $clearfield_search_label.prev('br').remove();
                                $clearfield_search_label.remove();
                                $clearfield_link_label.prev('br').remove();
                                $clearfield_link_label.remove();
                                //Removal of fields
                                $clearfield_link.remove();
                                $clearfield_search.remove();
     }
     alert("Remove attempt completed");
};
```

In addition to just making it a regular function, I cached the completed jQuery objects rather than caching strings that are later used to create jQuery objects. I personally like to put a dollar sign in variables that are jQuery objects, but that's just me. You don't need to.

Comment: Many thanks for all the feedback and advice - all seems to be working now - much appreciated - many thanks again!